# python list problem, which function should I use?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Here are the directions:

```
list of teeth_2years:['primary central incisor', 'primary lateral incisor', 'primary canine', 'primary first molar', 'primary second molar']
```

Initialize `teeth_6years` as a copy of `teeth_2years`.

In `teeth_6years`:

Assign 'permanent central incisor' to the index containing 'primary central incisor'.
Assign 'permanent first molar' to the index containing 'primary first molar'.
Assign 'permanent lateral incisor' to the index containing 'primary lateral incisor'.
Print teeth_6years out.

my code:

```
teeth_6years = teeth_2years.copy()
teeth_6years.insert(0,'permanent central incisor')
teeth_6years.insert(3,'permanent first molar')
teeth_6years.insert(1,'permanent lateral incisor')
print(teeth_6years)
```

the output:

```
['permanent central incisor', 'permanent lateral incisor', 'primary central incisor', 'primary lateral incisor', 'permanent first molar', 'primary canine', 'primary first molar', 'primary second molar']
```

the problem:
I think I am supposed to replace the spot on the index? instead i am just adding to the list. What would you do?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this?

```
teeth_6years = teeth_2years[:]
teeth_6years[0] = 'permanent central incisor'
teeth_6years[3] = 'permanent first molar'
teeth_6years[1] = 'permanent lateral incisor'
print(teeth_6years)
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically you just need to get the list, and pick the index in the list you want to change and do as the following with your variables:

```
my_list = ['cat', 'dog', 'bunny', 'frog']

my_list[0] = 'bird'
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest something like this:

```
teeth_2years = ['primary central incisor', 'primary lateral incisor', 'primary canine', 'primary first molar', 'primary second molar']

teeth_6years = teeth_2years.copy()

# loop throught the elements of the list
for i in range(len(teeth_6years)):

    # whenever an element's value match to those should be replaced
        # replace with the proper value

    if teeth_6years[i] == 'primary central incisor':
        teeth_6years[i] = 'permanent central incisor'

    elif teeth_6years[i] == 'primary first molar':
        teeth_6years[i] = 'permanent first molar'

    elif teeth_6years[i] == 'primary lateral incisor':
        teeth_6years[i] = 'permanent lateral incisor'

for x in teeth_6years:
    print(x)
```